# How to improve Silverlight development process productivity of UI & MVVM in particular

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am currently developing for Silverlight 4.0 and after mostly creating class libraries with TDD in usual C# (before SL) I can say that my current process is way slower than I am used to. (I think this can be said about any UI code compared to library classes, but here I think its really serious issue for me.)

I am wondering what techniques can be recommended to increase SL development performance.

I am mainly concerned about hard to test code (from my POV) - MVVM & UI - what can be done to improve performance here, I am thinking maybe theres a way to use a smaller sandbox somehow and test/debug control behaviour outside of scope of whole application, its pretty clear to me that me running whole application to test whether a new dialog box works correctly isnt fastest way and I could improve performance if I had a way to test this dialog alone for example, and there are probably other ways I cannot think of that can be a solution too.

**EDIT:** 1)here is something that I found useful , for TDD there is now a project that allows console runner to run tests so you dont have to run silverlight tests in browser & can integrate in your build process [LightHouse](http://blog.roboblob.com/2011/03/22/lighthouse_silverlight_unit_test_runner_project_released/)

2) found following page, it provides some idea about a possible approach one could use to test view:
http://fohjin.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-test-your-xaml-behavior-using.html
there is no magic beautiful way and this one can be utilized but having to name all controls for example is a must to get this to work which isnt very good often

Comment: Speed of development isn't the best way of creating applications. About testing dialog boxes, it isn't so bad to run an entire application. BOr you can use DesignData files for other controls. Anyway this question isn't clear to me, I don't know how to answer.

Comment: I'm interested in what you learn from this question.  In my experience, the most brittle aspect of SL development particularly with MVVM is in the binding.  If there was a way to automate the testing of the binding expressions in the XAML I would be all for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Statlight](http://statlight.codeplex.com/) for the build server.

[AgUnit](http://agunit.codeplex.com/) to allow resharper to run silverlight tests.

[WebAii](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx) for automation testing.

I'm not a fan of SLUT, as to run an individual test you have to cut and paste its name, and it doesnt remember it until you let it run all the way through, which I rarely do if I'm debugging.

Comment: god running tests from Resharper is amazing, thanks Dave. I only tested AgUnit and already can breathe much better!

Comment: Agreed. It made me upgrade resharper!

Comment: me too. Wow I am very thankful for this. This is exactly what I was looking for when I was asking. Ill say it again: running SL tests from resharper is AMAZING.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use slut?

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut

she will do what you want and pretend she enjoys it

Comment: sure I did, as you can see from LightHouse project link , it allows to run SL unit tests from console too

Comment: Cool, but i dont think you ahve te lighthouse link in there when i answerd ;)